# Send HTML through Ajax POST

Tags: html, ajax

I have this code which works with no errors when sending "simple text" through Ajax post.
But when I want to send "**html**" to the server, my code will fail **sometimes**.

```js
var message = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();

if(message.length > 0)
{
    message = Base64.encode(message);
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('');
    
    var parameters = 'message=' + message;
    var url = "ChatResponse.aspx";
    ajaxPost.open("POST", url, true);
    ajaxPost.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    ajaxPost.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", parameters.length);
    ajaxPost.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    ajaxPost.send(parameters);
}
```

Will not fail for

```
asdasd<strong>asdasd</strong> [base64:]
YXNkYXNkPHN0cm9uZz5hc2Rhc2Q8L3N0cm9uZz4=
```

but will fail for

```
a<strong>a</strong> [base64:]
YTxzdHJvbmc+YTwvc3Ryb25nPg==
```

What is wrong?

Comment: What do you get on the server side? Do you get nothing or something that is garbled? Does it raise an error of somekind?

Comment: no request is made to the server, my POST call stops in the browser somewhere

Comment: Does it make a different what browser you use?

Comment: Also, have you tried alerting the value of message to see if it actually had the HTML in it and if it's already encoded?

Comment: yes, for <b>html</b> the encoded value is %3Cstrong%3Ehtml%3C/strong%3E

Comment: If you post something other than just the message or remove the message completely, do you get something on the server?

Comment: Can you post just plain text without using TinyMCE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not being encoded before being sent.  I believe TinyMCE has a method that allows you to get the encoded content.  You may also want to try taking the content from the textarea using the value property.

Comment: Does getContent() not do that?

Comment: If I remember right tinymce has two methods to get encoded and unencoded.